# Spring embeddeb db table already exists error

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying run a spring boot application with an embedded db. During initialization of beans (because of some reason ?) my table creation script is called twice and second call fails with "table already exists" error. Below is my code, what can be the problem.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

private static EmbeddedDatabase dataSource;

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new DbPlaceholderConfigurer(dataSource());
}


@Bean
public static EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
    if(dataSource == null) {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder databaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        databaseBuilder.addScript("classpath:schema.sql");
        //databaseBuilder.setName("test");
        databaseBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2);
        EmbeddedDatabase build = databaseBuilder.build();
        initPopulate(build);
        dataSource = build;
    }
    return dataSource;
}

private static void initPopulate(EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase) {
    try {
        Connection connection = embeddedDatabase.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement prepareStatement;
        prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Settings VALUES (?,?,?)");
        prepareStatement.setInt(1, 1);
        prepareStatement.setString(2, "testKey");
        prepareStatement.setString(3, "testVal");
        prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error("Error ", e);
    }
}
}
```

Error log is below:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SETTINGS" already exists; SQL   statement:
CREATE TABLE Settings( id INT PRIMARY KEY, testKey VARCHAR(100), testValue VARCHAR(100) ) [42101-192]
```

Note: I can boot my application successfully by setting following property but i really curious why spring is calling the table creation script twice.

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Note2: Table creation script(schema.sql) is like below:

```
create table contacts (
 id identity,
 firstname varChar(30) not null,
 lastName varChar(30) not null,
 phoneNumber varChar(20),
 emailAddress varChar(50)
);
```

Answer (score 10):

I found that this was happening when I had my H2 **schema.sql** and **data.sql** files in my **src/main/resources** directory and also referenced in my **DatabaseConfig**:

```
@Bean
public DataSource embeddedDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:data.sql")
        .build();
}
```

I was initializing the in-memory DB in my **DatabaseConfig** class, and then Spring Boot was trying to load the same data based on [its configuration rules](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

To get rid of the error remove **schema.sql** and **data.sql** from **dataSource()**.

```
@Bean
public DataSource embeddedDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
}
```

Comment: Notice that it's not a directly answer. You didn't give a solution. I suggest you to edit your answer  and complete it.

Comment: The issue is  that **schema.sql** is defined in **dataSource()** method as being in **"classpath:schema.sql"**.  This means that the schema.sql will get run twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your database initialization code. `Spring Boot` provides it out of box.
 The following properties should give you an idea:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true # Populate the database using 'data.sql'.
spring.datasource.separator=; # Statement separator in SQL initialization scripts.
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding= # SQL scripts encoding.
```

See the other properties in the `Spring Boot` [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).