# In Spring Boot JPA, why would I get "Table already exists; SQL statement:"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am building a Spring Boot project with JPA repositories. For testing, I use an H2 in-memory database. I initialize the database with a schema.sql file, an excerpt of which is:

```
CREATE TABLE `config_user_preset_dataclass` (
  `user_preset_dataclass_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_preset_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataclass_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ngdp_audit_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ngdp_update_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_preset_dataclass_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_config_user_preset_dataclass_1` (`user_preset_id`,`dataclass_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_config_user_preset_dataclass_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_preset_id`) REFERENCES `config_user_preset` (`user_preset_id`)
);
```

The schema.sql is wired to initialize the database by setting the database URL to `DB_URL=jdbc:h2:mem:data360;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql';DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false`, and I have verified that this is functional.

In my `src/test/resources/application.properties`, I have set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`, so there should not be any secondary attempt to generate the table. However, when I run a simple test to save the JPA model, I get:

```
2018-04-11 17:59:17.847 ERROR 11540 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "CONFIG_USER_PRESET" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE `config_user_preset` (
  `user_preset_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `preset_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ngdp_audit_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ngdp_update_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_preset_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_user_preset_config_1` (`user_id`,`preset_name`)
) [42101-196]
```

The error clearly indicates that something is attempting to generate the table again.

What could it be?

Interestingly, this error goes away if I use the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` for the primary key. However, this causes another problem, so I'm not able to do that.

[edit]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "config_user_preset_dataclass")
public class UserPresetDataclass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_preset_dataclass_id")
    private long presetDataClassId;

    @Column(name = "user_preset_id")
    private long userPresetId;

    @Column(name = "dataclass_name")
    private String dataclassName;

...
```

[/edit]

Comment: SpringBoot has a complex mechanism to check the type of database, hibernate/jpa properties etc and decide whether to initialize the database using sql script or not. We just need to configure spring.datasource.initialization-mode to make it work. Just curious to know why you want to use INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql' instead of using the features provided out of the box?

Comment: in your `src/main/resources/application.properties` is your property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` set to `update`?

Comment: I am using the INIT=RUNSCRIPT stuff because the initilization-mode did not work, nor did the out-of-the-box stuff. There is probably something in my company's terrible wrapper of spring boot that breaks it.

Comment: I had the same problem (schema.sql executed twice), I just did a Maven update and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

Probably your DB still in memory, that's the reason why you're getting this error.
I propose two alternatives:

1. Change the SQL statements.
   Instead of `CREATE TABLE config_user_preset...` you can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS config_user_preset ...`
2. If you're using Spring, you're able to create an embedded DB. Check here [Spring embeddeb db table already exists error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110698/5535262).